# Can't reload module that is in another folder but also in sys.path

Tags: python, import, module, reload

I'm having some troubles reloading a module that is in another directory but is in sys.path.

```
>>> from module_from_another_dir import *
>>> from importlib import reload
>>> reload(module_from_another_dir)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'module_from_another_dir' is not defined
```

So as you can see I can import it, but I can't reload it later.

Comment: That's because you imported every element of the module, but not the module itself

Comment: thanks, it works now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you import module like this

```
from module_from_another_dir import *
```

then Python knows only new methods and "forgets" about module name. However, you can import your module as

```
import module_from_another_dir
```

and you will be able to reload it easily.